# Bootstrap carousel formatting and styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

Below I have a sample bootstrap carousel bit of code. I am not happy with how the default appearance looks, so I am trying to modify it to look a little more like I want it to. I have tried using inspecting to change and plug in values, but can't quite get the CSS down to do what I want it to. Is there a way I can make the 'caption' text full width on the bottom of the image (instead of centered and only about 85% width), and move the indicator dots below the slider, centered with a black background?

I don't want anybody to write me the code, but I would like some help figuring out how to do it myself.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="sites/default/files/images/wow2.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Let's Play!</h3>
              <p>Let's have some fun!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="sites/default/files/images/wow3.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              Let's play again!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```